# error in running valgrind for powerpc

Tags: linux, valgrind

I have successfully cross compiled valgrid for PPC85xx architecture. I have following file

```
./coregrind/valgrind
./coregrind/vgpreload_core-ppc32-linux.so
./memcheck/memcheck-ppc32-linux
./memcheck/vgpreload_memcheck-ppc32-linux.so
./default.supp
```

I did put these files in `/home/valg11` folder on target folder and exported the libraries as

```
export VALGRIND_LIB=/home/valg11
```

I am running valgrind and getting this error.

```
[root@85xx valg11]# ./valgrind -v /home/val
==988== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==988== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==988== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==988== Command: /home/val
==988== 
--988-- Valgrind options:
--988--    -v
--988-- Contents of /proc/version:
--988--   Linux version 2.6.32 (somya@somya-HP-Pro-3330-MT) (gcc version 4.2.2) #230 Mon Oct 12 14:02:51 IST 2015
--988-- 
--988-- Arch and hwcaps: PPC32, BigEndian, ppc32-int-flt-FX-GX
--988-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 65536
--988-- Valgrind library directory: /home/valg11
--988-- Reading syms from /lib/ld-2.8.so
--988-- Reading syms from /home/val
--988-- Reading syms from /home/valg11/memcheck-ppc32-linux
--988--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--988-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--988-- Reading suppressions file: /home/valg11/default.supp
==988== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-988-by-root-on-???
==988== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-988-by-root-on-???
==988== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-988-by-root-on-???
==988== 
==988== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
==988== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
==988== or are doing some strange experiment):
==988==   /home/valg11/../../bin/vgdb --pid=988 ...command...
==988== 
==988== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
==988==   /path/to/gdb /home/val
==988== and then give GDB the following command
==988==   target remote | /home/valg11/../../bin/vgdb --pid=988
==988== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
==988== 
==988== error 22 Invalid argument
==988== error VG_(am_shared_mmap_file_float_valgrind) /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-988-by-root-on-???
```

As suggested somewhere I did run valgrind without vgdb but valgrind is not detecting memory leak and giving illegal instruction error.

```
[root@85xx valg11]# ./valgrind -v --vgdb=no /home/val
==995== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==995== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==995== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==995== Command: /home/val
==995== 
--995-- Valgrind options:
--995--    -v
--995--    --vgdb=no
--995-- Contents of /proc/version:
--995--   Linux version 2.6.32 (somya@somya-HP-Pro-3330-MT) (gcc version 4.2.2) #230 Mon Oct 12 14:02:51 IST 2015
--995-- 
--995-- Arch and hwcaps: PPC32, BigEndian, ppc32-int-flt-FX-GX
--995-- Page sizes: currently 4096, max supported 65536
--995-- Valgrind library directory: /home/valg11
--995-- Reading syms from /lib/ld-2.8.so
--995-- Reading syms from /home/val
--995-- Reading syms from /home/valg11/memcheck-ppc32-linux
--995--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
--995-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
--995-- Reading suppressions file: /home/valg11/default.supp
disInstr(ppc): unhandled instruction: 0x10E40301
                 primary 4(0x4), secondary 769(0x301)
==995== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4018ff0.
==995==    at 0x4018FF0: memcpy (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995==    by 0x40021C3: _dl_start_final (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995==    by 0x4015F8B: _start (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==995== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
==995== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
==995==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
==995==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
==995== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
==995==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
==995==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
==995== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
==995== probably kill your program.
==995== 
==995== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL)
==995==  Illegal opcode at address 0x4018FF0
==995==    at 0x4018FF0: memcpy (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995==    by 0x40021C3: _dl_start_final (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995==    by 0x4015F8B: _start (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
==995== 
==995== HEAP SUMMARY:
==995==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==995==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==995== 
==995== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==995== 
==995== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 2)
--995-- 
--995-- used_suppression:      4 dl-hack1 /home/valg11/default.supp:1205
==995== 
==995== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 2)
Illegal instruction
```

I don't know what the problem is, Has someone run valgrind on powerpc architecture ? What procedure should I follow ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely is the second cause it logs:

> The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
>   i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
>   you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.

It seems likely that your executable was compiled with a target instruction set which is not fully supported by the version of valgrind you are using.  Assuming you've built valgrind from the latest sources, the easiest fix for your problem is probably to recompile your executable with a more restrictive (usually older) version of your target ISA.  We may be able to help you figure out how to do that if you provide your full compiler version and command line information.

Comment: i am using latest valgrind version valgrind-3.11.0. This is my compiler version information,  
ELDK version 4.2
ppc_85xx: Build 2008-04-01

Comment: To compile the test app I am exporting path of toolchain /opt/eldk-4.2-85xx/usr/bin and running ppc-linx-gcc test_app.c -o val command to cross compile my test app.

Comment: Does your compiler have options to configure the target ISA, a la GCC's `-march` option?

Comment: i think it does not have march option. i did run, ppc_85xx-gcc -march=native test.c -o val  and got following output . cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-march=native"

Comment: however it does have mtune option. I did run ppc_85xx-gcc -mtune=native test.c -o val_mtune and folowwing output. test.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -mtune= switch

Comment: I see that valgrind powerpc architecture up to and including Power8. I have power85xx architecture. supports http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html.

Comment: i have come to know that ppc_85xx is based on QorIQ processors with e500v2 core. there is an open bug here. I guess valgrind doesn't support this. https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=321396

Answer (score 0):

Your host system maybe has CPU detection in memcpy/memmove in order to decide which version of the function to run - and valgrind does not handle this well. Try to make your own version of memcpy and friends into a dynamic library, and force-load this into your application.

(I had to do this on my ARM system)

libmemcmp source:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int
memcmp(
    const void *s1,                     /* First string. */
    const void *s2,                     /* Second string. */
    size_t      n)                      /* Length to compare. */
{
    unsigned char u1, u2;

    for ( ; n-- ; s1++, s2++) {
        u1 = * (unsigned char *) s1;
        u2 = * (unsigned char *) s2;
        if ( u1 != u2) {
            return (u1-u2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

void *memcpy(void *v_dst, const void *v_src, size_t c)
{
        const char *src = v_src;
        char *dst = v_dst;

        /* Simple, byte oriented memcpy. */
        while (c--)
                *dst++ = *src++;

        return v_dst;
}
```

LD_PRELOAD=/home/pi/libmemcmp.so valgrind --leak-check=full ./myapp

Comment: Does it still say ==995==    at 0x4018FF0: memcpy (in /lib/ld-2.8.so)
or is /lib/ld-2.8.so replaced with your library? If it has not been replace, the function override did not take place